# How do mechanical engineers, in practice, account for drag/air resistance when designing machines?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machine-design

This is a question I've had on my mind for a while. I was recently looking at machine in operation: it was a machine which had a bunch of vertical spindles holding yarn bobbins, rotating at a high speed, side-by-side. If someone wanted to analyse the dynamics of one of these spindles, they would need some sort of model for the torque due to drag acting on it.

Maybe, data on a large number of drag coefficients is available, and this is what's used, I thought initially. But then looking more closely, surely the streams generated would be merging into another. These bobbins aren't independant of each other in that sense. Quick googling revealed this is called interference drag.

This made me curious about how a mechanical engineer that's designing a machine, who isn't necessarily an aerodynamics expert, goes about analysing the dynamics of situations like this. In many situations, parts of a machine must be moving in complicated ways/trajectories, and at high speeds. Applying the drag equation here seems inappropriate since it appears that $C_D$ is experimentally determined for an object moving in a straight path. Also, like above, the streams from the different moving parts would be merging into each other

So how then, in practice, do mechanical engineers do such analyses when they're designing machines? Any part of the machine is moving at high enough speeds that you would need to account for drag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases, probably a majority, they ignore air drag, and simply design the torque capability of the engine as enough to deliver the required output, plus some sizable margin to overcome sources of friction.

That is a general engineering principle. If you have a system that is difficult or impossible to model, you model it as a simple system and add margin (or safety factors) to the capability.  Then all you have to do is show by estimation that the unknown factors are too small to compromise the result.

For example if I'm designing a table, I may not be able to model the stress distribution of every object that could be put on the table, nor the complex transient loading that occurs when items are dropped on it and the table vibrates. But I do know that the force necessary to arrest the fall will not be more than a completely elastic collision from height $H$ per the following formula:

$$F= 2 \frac Mt \sqrt{2gH}$$

(see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/313909/313823))

Let's say this value is twice the weight of the item.

So if I put a weight limit on the table of 400 lb, I would design the table structurally to withstand at least 800 lb.  The goal is to calculate the worst case loading scenario that will envelop all the unknown conditions, and design for that condition, plus margin.

For your specific question about air drag, that is going to be insignificant for the motions of mechanisms.  It is more relevant for vehicles in motion.

Comment: Other alternatives would be to build a prototype, or find a similar machine, and test it.

Comment: @RC_23 In your last point you mention that air drag is going to be insignificant for the motions of mechanisms. So, generally speaking air drag is simply ignored for machine-design related calculations? Is this something you're guessing is the case or do you directly know this is true

Comment: It is relevant for some mechanisms, especially ones whose function is related to air movement, like fans.  If you have something that is fin-like (thin, wide surface area) and moves quickly, you may have to consider drag in the design. But the designer would make a simple $C_D$ approximation and add margin, and certainly not attempt to model all the convectiom currents.   Or run a test.  For most internals of machines (gears, pistons, shafts, etc) I can't imagine air drag is considered, as the forces between the parts in physical contact are much greater.